# How can I script the Descriptions of Columns in MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-server

I have a table named `Assignment` in my **Azure SQL Server** (version 12.0.1400).

The table itself, as well as most of the columns, have `Description` filled in. I've entered those `Description` values using the **Table Designer** in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS version 18.1 <s>15.0.18131.0</s>).

My problem is that, when I **script** the table, I only see the `Description` of the **table**, but I can't see the `Description`s of columns, which are clearly visible in **Object Explorer**.

If you look at the screenshot below, you'll see that the table `Assignment`, as well as a column, `AssignmentId`, have `Description`s:

[image]

And when I script the table, the resulting SQL code is:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Assignment]    Script Date: 09-Jul-19 13:52:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assignment](
    [AssignmentId] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [HITId] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [WorkerId] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [HITStatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [HITTitle] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [HITTypeId] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [HITGroupId] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [HITCreationTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [Deadline] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [AcceptTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [SubmitTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [ApprovalTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [RejectionTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [AssignmentStatus] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ImageUrl] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [AnswerFreeText] [text] NULL,
    [SimpleCheckFinishedTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [SimpleCheckStatus] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assignment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Assignment_AssignmentStatus_Enumeration_Constraint] CHECK  (([AssignmentStatus]='Rejected' OR [AssignmentStatus]='Approved' OR [AssignmentStatus]='Submitted'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assignment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Assignment_AssignmentStatus_Enumeration_Constraint]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assignment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Assignment_HITStatus_Enumeration_Constraint] CHECK  (([HITStatus]='Disposed' OR [HITStatus]='Reviewing' OR [HITStatus]='Reviewable' OR [HITStatus]='Unassignable' OR [HITStatus]='Assignable'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assignment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Assignment_HITStatus_Enumeration_Constraint]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'The Assignment data structure represents a single assignment of a HIT to a Worker. The assignment tracks the Worker''s efforts to complete the HIT, and contains the results for later retrieval. ' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Assignment'
GO
```

The only `Description` in the resulting SQL script is the one for the table itself, and not for the columns.

I've also checked the options of Object Explorer:

[image]

But I still can't get those Description values for columns in the resulting SQL script.

How can I can extract them using **Script Table** in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: FWIW SSMS version 18.0 on SQL Server scripts these description properties with no further options set. You could try and see if "generate script for dependent objects" makes a difference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wrote my SSMS version wrong (it's version 18.1, but Copy Info from "About" screen displays the component version as I reported). Anyway, I've also set "Generate script for dependent objects" to True, and I ran "Script Table as" again. Unfortunately, still no Description values for the columns themselves :(

Comment: The Description values are obviously there, because I can already see them when I run the following: `SELECT objtype, objname, name, value  
FROM fn_listextendedproperty (NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Assignment', 'column', default);` , but I can't extract them into a script via SMSS even if I script entire database and all objects

Comment: When I update the Description field on a column in my test table, it creates an extended property called "MS_Description" with that value. Then when I do a right click>Script Table, I get an extended property at the end of my script. Are you not getting the extended property with your script? Like so: `EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'TEST' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ComputedColumns', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Comp1'
GO` Might just be an Azure problem specifically?

Comment: Then that might be an incompatibility in Azure, possibly in combination with SSMS itself. You can [submit an issue](http://aka.ms/sqlfeedback). Working around it "manually" is simple enough (you can just manually generate `sp_addextendedproperty` calls with the output you get from `fn_listextendedproperty`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert and @JacobH, I think you're right suggesting a bug, because I've tried something similar on an *on-premise*, *non-Azure* MS SQL Server 2016, and Script Table returned `EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description' ...` lines for all the Columns whose `Description`s I've filled in the Table Designer.